# Django update model after condition

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model like this

```
class Foo(models.Model):
      bet = models.IntegerField()
      end_date = models.DateTimeField() \\some date in the future
      is_canceled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I need automatically set **is_canceled = True** when **end_date = datetime.now()**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/) that will be periodically run from `cron` and change field value

```
now = datetime.now()
Foo.objects.filter(end_date__lte=now).update(is_canceled=True)
```

But it's better to make that field dynamic

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bet = models.IntegerField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField() \\some date in the future

    @property
    def is_canceled(self):
        if self.end_date <= datetime.now():
            return True
        else:
            return False

some_foo = Foo.objects.first()
if some_foo.is_canceled:
    ...
```